# Rails Fakerを使ってテストデータ生成

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, rubygems

Ruby on Railsで開発しています。
DB(mysql)にテストデータを入れるためにFaker gemを使っています。
https://github.com/stympy/faker　を参照してほとんどのデータを入れることができましたが、これだけではできないところがあります。

1. Boolean型の場合、True/Falseが必要ですが、上記のところでは見つけられませんでした。
   （0 または 1でも大丈夫でしょうかね..）
2. 「時間：分：秒」だけ必要ですが、「2014-09-19 07:03:30 -0700」のような形式しかありませんね..
3. 例えばAとBという値があり、ランダムでどっちかの値を入れたいんです。他の値は要りません。
   この場合、どうすればできますか？別にFakerは必要なさそうに思われますが..

上記の問題を解決できる方法を教えてください！

Answer (score 1):

テストデータを作るとすれば、こんな感じでしょうか。
（Kimさんがどんなコードを書いているのかわからないので、こちらの想像で書いています。）

```ruby
schedule = Schedule.new

# 1. true/falseの設定はFakerを使わない
schedule.repeat = true # false でも可

# 2. ランダムな日時から時分秒だけを文字列化（例："07:31:51"）
schedule.scheduled_time = Faker::Time.between(DateTime.now - 1, DateTime.now).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

# 3. large または small をランダムにセット
schedule.room = %w(large small).sample

schedule.save!
```

質問のようなケースだと無理にFakerを使わなくてもいいのでは？という気がしますね。